# How to search for a comma-separated string in a database table in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

How to search for a comma-separated string in a database table in mySQL.

Suppose, I have a string in variable `$facilities='breakfast,dinner,lunch'` and in my database I have a string saved in a field called `facilities` **having values** `breakfast,dinner,clothing,lunch,hot water`.

How do I get the row having values `$facilities`?

Comment: You can work with this select * from table where field_name like '%$fieldname%'

Comment: You need to implement user define function which will take 2 inputs and returns your match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work like this i hope this is your requirement

```
select * from table where field_name like '%$fieldname%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   FIND_IN_SET('lunch', 'breakfast,dinner,lunch')
```

**EDIT:**

SELECT  *
    FROM    tableName
    WHERE   FIND_IN_SET('lunch', food_column)

food_column is the name of the column where the string 'breakfast,dinner,lunch' is stored

Comment: No. This answer is partial. Because `'find_in_set'` in your query searching only `'lunch'` in a set. What about other strings in the user variables? And hence this is an incomplete answer.

Comment: Look at Rowland's Answer

Comment: You don't seem understood my comment and as well Rowland's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to break apart the comma separated string first, and include a clause for each, so for that input you'd generate SQL like (assuming you want rows that have all three, and maybe other flags set):

```sql
SELECT      *

FROM        YourTable

WHERE       FIND_IN_SET('breakfast', facilities)
    AND     FIND_IN_SET('dinner', facilities)
    AND     FIND_IN_SET('lunch', facilities)
```

You can break the string apart in PHP with something a little like:

```
$facilities='breakfast,dinner,lunch';
$desired = explode ( "," , $facilities );
```

And just use a loop to build your SQL